# Problema con trigger stock

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger

Soy bastante nuevo en estos temas y tengo que hacer un ejercicio en el que tengo que restar el stock  cada vez que hago un insert en la tabla lineas_pedido y que además el stock no tenga número negativos. El trigger para restar, sabría hacerlo, el problema viene si quiero que el stock no tenga valores negativos, por ejemplo si al restar da un numero negativo el stock sea igual a 0.

Las tablas serían tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER ejercicio7
after INSERT ON lineas_pedido 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE stock7 smallint;
    SET stock7=(SELECT stock from libros inner join lineas_pedido on libros.codigo=lineas_pedido.codLibro where libros.codigo=new.codLibro);
        IF (@stock7-new.cantidad)<0 then 
            UPDATE libros set libros.stock=0 where codigo=new.codLibro;
        END IF;
        IF (@stock7-new.cantidad)>0 then
            UPDATE libros set stock=libros.stock-new.cantidad where codigo=new.codLibro;
        END IF;
    
    
END;
//
```

La cuestión es que no se me actualiza ningún registro. Agradecería cualquier ayuda , muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, pásanos el dataset para las pruebas

Comment: @DavidJP  esto quieres?, perdona si no te entiendo, soy muy novato con esto T_T INSERT INTO libros (codigo,titulo,descripcion,precio,stock) values ('zzz','Carbono Alterado','Ciencia ficcion',20,50);
INSERT INTO pedidos (codigo,idCliente,fecha,importe,estado) values ('qweqwe','1234asd',NOW(),20,'Enviado');
INSERT into lineas_pedido (codPedido,codLibro,cantidad) VALUES ('qweqwe','zzz',1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa de no actualizar ningún registro es la resta `@stock7 - new.cantidad`, me explico, para MySQL `@stock7` y `stock7` son variables distintas. `@stock7` es una [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) mientras que `stock7` es una [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-local-variable.html). Disculpe, pero la documentación está en Inglés.

Al momento de la ejecución del disparador (trigger) `@stock7` tiene un valor de `NULL`, por ello, `NULL - new.cantidad` será `NULL` y no se cumplen las condiciones de los `IF`.

Una opción de cambio a su disparador (trigger) puede ser la siguiente:

```SQL
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `ejercicio7`
AFTER INSERT ON `lineas_pedido`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE `stock7` SMALLINT DEFAULT (
    SELECT `stock`
    FROM `libros`
      INNER JOIN `lineas_pedido` ON
        `libros`.`codigo` = `lineas_pedido`.`codLibro`
    WHERE `libros`.`codigo` = NEW.`codLibro`
  );
  DECLARE `new_stock7` SMALLINT DEFAULT `stock7` - NEW.`cantidad`;

/*
  SET stock7=(SELECT stock from libros inner join lineas_pedido on libros.codigo=lineas_pedido.codLibro where libros.codigo=new.codLibro);
  IF (@stock7-new.cantidad)<0 then
    UPDATE libros set libros.stock=0 where codigo=new.codLibro;
  END IF;
  IF (@stock7-new.cantidad)>0 then
    UPDATE libros set stock=libros.stock-new.cantidad where codigo=new.codLibro;
  END IF;
*/

  UPDATE `libros`
  SET `libros`.`stock` = IF(`new_stock7` < 0, 0, `new_stock7`)
  WHERE `codigo` = NEW.`codLibro`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f010c7e97624b14b71f966f5e25858d).

También sería posible lograr la actualización de registros que necesita en una única sentencia `UPDATE`.

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias de verdad, me has aclarado mucho. 
Cuando dices que "También sería posible lograr la actualización de registros que necesita en una única sentencia UPDATE." ¿Te refieres a hacerlo sin las variables?, pregunto por entender más, pero la respuesta que me has dado es más que válida, muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Alex correcto, al hacer una única sentencia `UPDATE` no sería necesario el uso de variables, [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c0b4c721005aca0f428c8b1ee47e00c) de ejemplo.

Comment: Buah, me has ayudado muchisimo tio, muchas gracias.